# Optimize nested loops c#

Tags: c#, loops, optimization, nested, parallel.for

I'm trying to optimize the following peace of code - there are multiple iterations which consumes a lot of time. Looked through Parallel.For examples but don't understand how to use them in my case as I have "double" variables in each "for" loop. Can you please help? Thanks

```
public void maximization ()
    {
        int ii = 0; // counter to alter file name
        int jj = 0; // counter for all output strings

        string[] calculation;

        ArrayList array = new ArrayList(); // temporary array for optimized parameters

        for (pr_lower1 = -0.02; pr_lower1 <= 0.0; pr_lower1 = pr_lower1 + 0.002) //11
        {
            for (pr_upper1 = 0.002; pr_upper1 <= 0.02; pr_upper1 = pr_upper1 + 0.002) //10
            {
                for (OI_lower1 = 0.02; OI_lower1 <= 0.1; OI_lower1 = OI_lower1 + 0.01) //9
                {
                    for (pr_lower2 = -0.02; pr_lower2 <= 0.0; pr_lower2 = pr_lower2 + 0.002) //11
                    {
                        for (pr_upper2 = 0.002; pr_upper2 <= 0.02; pr_upper2 = pr_upper2 + 0.002) //10
                        {
                            for (OI_lower2 = -0.1; OI_lower2 <= 0.0; OI_lower2 = OI_lower2 + 0.01) //11
                            {
                                for (OI_upper2 = 0.01; OI_upper2 <= 0.1; OI_upper2 = OI_upper2 + 0.01) //10
                                {
                                    for (stop = 0.05; stop <= 0.27; stop = stop + 0.02) //12
                                    {
                                        for (tp = 0.05; tp <= 0.27; tp = tp + 0.02) //12
                                        {                                                
                                            this.run_algo_max();
                                            jj++;
                                            string output = ret + " " + jj;
                                            array.Add(output);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            ii++;
            calculation = (String[])array.ToArray(typeof(string));
            array.Clear();
            File.WriteAllLines(Application.StartupPath + "\\results" + ii + ".txt", calculation);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you really need such number of loops?

Comment: unfortunately yes. I have several parameters to optimize and trying to find the best combination

Comment: There is much wrong about that example.

First, don't use class attributes when you plan on parallelizing anything. Pass all parameters as such into the `run_algo_max` method, and give back the return value as a regular return value. Otherwise, parallelizing will cause race conditions.

Second: Instead of calling `run_algo_max` directly, make it a delegate which can iterate over a selection of features to examine.
(TBC in next comment)

Comment: maybe if you could give the real code ... right now I can optimize this for you just by removing **all** of the `loop`s ;)

Comment: Your loop variables (i.e. `pr_lower2`, `pr_upper2`, etc) don't seem to be an input to anything and not clear where they are declared (scope that is), so how to optimize would really depend on how those are used.

Comment: Third, use heuristics. Do not compute the entire 1.7 million feature space. Sample sparse, evaluate the quality of the feature point right away, and push new points to examine back into the queue of points to examine. Examine carefully along which parameter derivation is low and make it more coarse along these first. Only increase sample rate on these as you have pinned parameters with higher derivation. Oh, and why the delegate? So you can achieve a separation between the code which queues new ponts and the code which is responsible for parallel (or offloaded) execution.

Comment: Loop variables are declared as public variables. They are used in run_algo_max() method

Comment: @RushanVakhitov Please never do that. Make them local, and pass them as parameters into your method. Same goes for the return value. Make sure you don't use ANY other data structures which could show side effects inside `run_algo_max()`, or parallelization means a lot of additional effort.

Comment: @Ext3h: If only it was just 1.7 million... its 1700 million.

Comment: @Guffa Ok, reading the suffix correctly might help. That's another good reason why this cries for the use of heuristics with a feedback queue.

Answer (score 1):

To parallelise that, you have to rewrite the `run_algo_max` method so that it takes the values as parameters and returns the result.

In this case you can send two parameters and calculate the corresponding values. (156816000 is the product of all loop lenghts except the first.) You can write the results directly to the file, that way you don't need to keep millions of strings in memory:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < 11; ii++) {
  int jj = ii * 156816000;
  File.WriteAllLines(
    Application.StartupPath + "\\results" + ii + ".txt",

    Enumerable.Range(0, 156816000)
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(n => this.run_algo_max(ii, n) + " " + (jj + n))
  );
}
```

The method would take the parameter, calculate the values, do the work and return the result:

```
public string run_algo_max(int ii, int n) {
  double pr_lower1 = -0.02 + ii * 0.002;
  double pr_upper1 = 0.002 + (n % 10) * 0.002; n /= 10;
  double OI_lower1 = 0.02 + (n % 9) * 0.01; n /= 9;
  // etc.
  double stop = 0.05 + (n % 12) * 0.02; n /= 12;
  double tp = 0.05 + n * 0.02;
  // do the work, produce a string "result"
  return result;
}
```

Comment: @Ext3h: The code doesn't allocate any array at all. The result from the `Select` is an `IEnumerable<string>` that is written to the file as the values are produced, as it's the `File.WriteAllLines` method that consumes the enumerable.

Comment: Thanks for your help, guys! In 1st part of the code where do you declare variable "n"? and how it works please?

Comment: @RushanVakhitov: The `n` variable is a parameter in a lambda expression. The lambda expression creates a delegate to a function equivalent to `string F(int n){ return this.run_algo_max(ii, n) + " " + (jj + n); }`. The `Select` method runs this function for each value produced by the `Enumerable.Range` method.

Comment: Feeling myself really stupid but I don't understand how the 2nd part of the code works.. Tried to "watch" the value of "n" in Locals window during debug - didn't help. "n" takes "random" values - and the debug jumps from one line of code to another.. Can you pls explain me? Thank you very much!

Comment: @RushanVakhitov: Consider a two dimensional 3x3 array containing `{{ 0,1,2 }, { 3,4,5 }, { 6,7,8}}`. From the number in the items you can calculate `x` as `n % 3` and `y` as `n / 3`. This is the same, but in eight dimensions (10x9x11x10x11x10x12x12), and the indexes are doubles.